# Long text will open on more button click

Tags: jquery, css

I have this long description text to show it to users. At first it will show a short part of this description. But there will be a "more >>" button which open the entire description. How can I do this by jquery or css.

```
<div class="desc">
    <h3>Product Description</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas vel dui aliquam, semper mauris sit amet, imperdiet purus. Fusce convallis, nisl at imperdiet tincidunt, libero dui euismod tortor, eu ornare justo orci quis felis. Morbi volutpat felis nisl, vel interdum nulla porttitor a. Aenean est risus, malesuada a orci at, aliquam mattis ipsum. Proin porttitor metus dapibus nulla tempor scelerisque. Morbi fringilla imperdiet dui, at molestie justo rutrum mattis. Nunc in ultricies lorem. Quisque ut orci nec nibh facilisis imperdiet ac sit amet lacus. Sed tempus condimentum velit et porta. Etiam in lectus sapien. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer tincidunt pulvinar lorem, vel placerat diam.</p>
</div>
```

**Edit:**

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/woldhag/nzx7K/2/)

This was my immediate idea. but It doesn't look good. Its not realistic to add extra spans everytime to  description text. I would love some clean solution.

Comment: where do you want the "more>>" button to show? (after how many characters?)

Comment: You could use scrollbars instead.

Comment: more>> button could be available after 3 or 4 lines.

Comment: In JS you can define some particular height that the block must have. And you may make it then less height with JS, and add a link to display rest of the text on click. Just an idea.

Comment: You should really show more effort on this, the fiddle sets up the problem but you didn't try anything on there.

Comment: @Dan I've edited my question. I had an idea but I was not happy with it so didn't posted it.

Comment: Ok, I wrote an answer below and it looks like the updated fiddle is a lot closer

Answer (score 1):

This does it for you, but you would have to manually define the break.  If you want to do so programmatically you should use a function that counts characters and places the break in a specific spot.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6uV2y/)

View:

```
<div class="desc">
     <h3>Product Description</h3>

    <p>Text before the break...
    <span class="more" style="display: none;">Text after the break...</span>
     <a href="#" class="click-more">More>></a>
    </p>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.click-more').click(function () {
    $(this).hide();
    $('.more').show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maxrbaldwin/nzx7K/4/). I edited yours a little bit and added two jQuery functions that can be toggled on different events. I stored the value of the whole string at the top of the page and then used substring to truncate it when an event is triggered. You can change the length of the string by changing the length value. Let me know if you have any questions.

```
var shorten = function(){
var text = $('.desc p').text();
var length = 100;
var shortString = text.substring(0, length);
$('.desc p').text(shortString); };

var unshorten = function(){
$('.desc p').text(longText);}
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple JavaScript solution here.

Consider this html:

```
<div class="desc">
     <h3>Product Description</h3>

    <p id="small" class="show">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas vel dui aliquam, semper mauris sit amet, imperdiet purus. Fusce convallis, nisl at imperdiet tincidunt, libero dui euismod tortor, eu ornare justo orci quis felis. Morbi volutpat felis nisl, vel interdum nulla porttitor a... </p>

        <p id="big" class="hide">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas vel dui aliquam, semper mauris sit amet, imperdiet purus. Fusce convallis, nisl at imperdiet tincidunt, libero dui euismod tortor, eu ornare justo orci quis felis. Morbi volutpat felis nisl, vel interdum nulla porttitor a. Aenean est risus, malesuada a orci at, aliquam mattis ipsum. Proin porttitor metus dapibus nulla tempor scelerisque. Morbi fringilla imperdiet dui, at molestie justo rutrum mattis. Nunc in ultricies lorem. Quisque ut orci nec nibh facilisis imperdiet ac sit amet lacus. Sed tempus condimentum velit et porta. Etiam in lectus sapien. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer tincidunt pulvinar lorem, vel placerat diam.</p>
    <a href="#" id="lnk">more >></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.desc {
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    width:400px;
    color: #555555;
}
.desc > p > span.more {
    color:blue;
    float: right;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.desc > a {
    color: #555555;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.hide {
    display:none;
}
.show {
    display:inline;
}
```

and the following JavaScript :

```
var lnk = document.getElementById('lnk');
var small = document.getElementById('small');
var big = document.getElementById('big');

lnk.addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (small.className === 'show') {
        small.className = 'hide';
        big.className = 'show';
        lnk.innerHTML ='<< less';
    } else {
        small.className = 'show';
        big.className = 'hide';
        lnk.innerHTML ='more>>';
    }
});
```

You can see this here: http://jsfiddle.net/jjF7R/2/

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

No additional html and little cosmetic css, lazy version.
[JSFiddle demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/nzx7K/9/).

Jquery added:

```
var p = $(".desc > p");
var t = p.text();
var len = t.length;
var max_len = 150;

if (len > max_len) {
    var visible = t.substr(0, max_len);
    var hidden = t.substr(max_len, len);
    p.empty().append(visible + "<span class='dots'>...</span><span class='more-text'>" + hidden + "</span>");
    $("<span class='more'>less>>></span>").insertAfter(".more-text");
}

function showHide() {
    var button = $(".more");
    var t = (button.text() == 'more>>>') ? 'less>>>' : 'more>>>';
    button.html(t);
    $(".more-text").toggle();
    $(".dots").toggle();
}

$(".more").click(showHide);
```